# Making automatic transition slideshow out of previously designed gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As title states, the website I have currently has a "click to go to next image" slide show as the banner image. I'm looking to turn it into a slideshow that automatically transitions from image to image but I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

The site can be found @ [rdesignmedia.com/testing/logo_you](http://rdesignmedia.com/testing/logo_you)

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="camera_container">
    <div class="camera_wrap" id="camera">
        <div data-src="images/page-1_slide1.jpg">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
                <div class="jumbotron jumbotron1">
                    <em>On Tour</em>
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <p>Engineered Elegance</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-src="images/page-1_slide2.jpg">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
                <div class="jumbotron jumbotron2">
                    <em>ELEVATE</em>
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <p>Your Brand Lives Here.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-src="images/page-1_slide3.jpg">
            <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <em>Tech Branding</em>
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <p>Stand out from the crowd with technological branding</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the site you can do this after the page loads:

```
// Creates an interval that runs the function every 2 seconds
setInterval(
    function () {
        // Finds the ul holding the little dots
        var ul = $(".camera_pag_ul");

        // Finds the currently selected dot
        var selected = ul.find('.cameracurrent');

        // Finds the next dot to click
        var next = selected.next('li');

        // If the next dot exists click it, else start over with first one
        if (next.length != 0) {
            next.click();
        }
        else {
            ul.find('li:first').click();
        }
    }, 2000
);
```

This works if I run it in the console on the site. This switches the image every 2 seconds. You can obviously change the `2000` to something else to increase the time the images is displayed before the next one shows.

Comment: How would I implement that exactly @Athiest?  I'm not that great with Java :(

Comment: @m.risk Do you have access to the site code? Where is that image thing initialized? Thats where I would paste this code. Directly after it.

Comment: @athiest. -  I do have access to the site code. That image banner is located right in the index page.  I'll paste it in after that and see what happens.

Comment: @athiestP3ace - When you said you ran it in the console on the site, where exactly do you mean?  I don't have access to the site files at my current station to test it but I'm curious to see how you tested it without the site files.

Comment: I opened the website and opened the developer console, in chrome its ctrl+shift+i, and pasted it into the console that opens with that shortcut and pressed enter.

Comment: Yep that's what I've been trying. Where do you paste it exactly though.  That's where I'm getting lost. I know how to open the console just where to paste that code to see it in action.  I'm truly sorry for my lack of knowledge. I'm a graphic designer turned aspiring coder and am trying to figure this out as best I can.  Again very sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Along top of the developer area that opens you should see some tabs. One is called console. Then there is a little area you can type in with a >. Paste it there and hit enter.

Comment: I tried it in the console and it works beautifully.  Thanks for the info.  I'll be able to figure out how to implement it into the coding I'm sure.  Thanks a million.

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!